# Magento Custom Module, Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction()

Tags: php, xml, layout, magento, controller

When I hit my module on this url http://localhost/xxx/index.php/TradeEnquiry I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   setFormAction() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\stockdisplays\app\code\local\Stock\Tradeenquiry\controllers\IndexController.php
>   on line 55

Line 55 is this:

```
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('tradeenquiryView')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
```

this is a fragment from my layout xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="tradeenquiry">
                <label>Trade Enquiry</label>
                <url>tradeenquiry</url>
                <title>Trade Enquiry</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
            </action>
    </reference>
</default>

<tradeenquiry_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="tradeenquiry"><title>Trade Enquiry</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="tradeenquiryView" template="tradeenquiry/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</tradeenquiry_index_index>
```

I dont get what the problem is? the block is correctly named 'tradeenquiryView'. The only thing I can think of is that the layout xml is cached somehow? As I have to hit the module on /TradeEnquiry and not /tradeenquiry like I have stated in my layout xml, so its almost as if its using an older version?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same exact problem you're having.

Comment: BTW, I tried to install Alan's module and passed the GET vars in, but nothing appeared.

Comment: Yeah for me it turned out to be a minor fault in one of the xml files. I when through them all with Beyond Compare, and made all the spacings and capitalisations the same as the contact module and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Like everything Magento, there's a numerous reasons this could be happening.

First, I'd avoid using a capital letter "V" when naming your blocks.  Although I don't **think** this would cause a problem (as names are references to URIs (core/textlist, etc.) and template filepath (/path/to/template.phtml)), there's a de-facto naming convention in the layout system of lowercase/underscore names which someone, somewhere (i.e Varien) may decide is an enforced convention.

Second, have you called

```
$this->loadLayout();
```

in your controller action before the line where you attempt to set the form action? Until you do this your Layout object won't have instantiated and/or have a reference to your block objects, which means

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('...')
```

will always return false.

Other debugging tips.  Try the following to make sure you're getting back the classes you think you should.

```
die(get_class($this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')));                                   
die(get_class($this->getLayout()));
```

Finally, if all that fails, go to the source of the layout object

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
```

And take a look at the getBlock method

```
public function getBlock($name)
{
    if (isset($this->_blocks[$name])) {
        return $this->_blocks[$name];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and start throwing in debug statements to see if you can figure out why the system isn't returning a reference to your block.  Don't forget to remove/not-check-in your debugging statements as this is core system code.

Comment: Thank again for another one of your comprehensive answers. 

Your points about $this->loadLayout(); and the capital V, im sure are valid, but that is the way the Magento Contacts module does it?

Ill debug like you say and then see what I get

Comment: I debugged getBlock and my block is not set so its returning a false. How can this be? Its set in the layout xml, is there somewhere else I need to look?

Comment: If _blocks is empty it's because you haven't called the controller's loadLayout method yet.  If _blocks isn't empty but lacks a "tradeenquiryView", then that means the final "page layout" doesn't have your tradeenquiryView block in it.  Can you grab the module at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087733/magento-my-account-layout-xml-problem/1088107#1088107

and post the results of showLayout=page and showLayout=handles?