# Magento Custom Forms

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm trying to build my own Request Catalog Form in Magento, heavily based on the Contacts module that comes out of the box.  I have set up my XML files:

1. ./app/etc/modules/RequestCatalog_RequestCatalog.xml
2. ./design/frontend/default/{theme}/layout/requestcatalog.xml
3. ./code/local/{namespace}/{module}/etc/config.xml

In my config.xml, I set my frontname to 'requestcatalog' and told it to use my module's controller.  However, when I visit http://app.com/requestcatalog I receive the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object
>   in
>   /path/to/root/public_html/app/code/local/RequestCatalog/RequestCatalog/controllers/IndexController.php
>   on line 55

Line 55 of IndexController.php looks like:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('requestcatalog')->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
```

I have my block named 'requestcatalog' defined in my layout XML.

I've searched SO and found a user w/ the same problem, however no solution was provided: [Magento Custom Module, Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098518/magento-custom-module-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setformaction)

My requestcatalog.xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="requestcatalog" ifconfig="requestcatalog/requestcatalog/enabled"><label>Request a Catalog</label><url>requestcatalog</url><title>Request a Catalog</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
    </reference>
</default>

<requestcatalog_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="requestcatalog"><title>Request a Catalog</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="requestcatalog" template="requestcatalog/form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</requestcatalog_index_index>
```

My IndexAction():

```
   public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('requestcatalog')
        ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );

    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098518/magento-custom-module-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setformaction

Comment: Can you post your entire indexAction method and the contents of requestcatalog.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento Custom Module, Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098518/magento-custom-module-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setformaction)