# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function addLink()

Tags: magento, widget

Whenever I try to do something in a popup window, live export or preview a transactioanl email I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addLink() on a non-object in
>   /home/jsrdirec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget.php
>   on line 65

Here is app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget.php:

```
  protected function _addBreadcrumb($label, $title=null, $link=null)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->addLink($label, $title, $link);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

There can be so many reasons for this , check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098518/magento-custom-module-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setformaction) for more information. Mean while you can try this hack to [fix](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6933/) your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I noticed it when I was trying to import products through the import interface.  The kicker was that two days before the problem started, everything was working fine.  My solution, as a temporary fix, was I edited the _addBreadCrumb function in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget.php to be

```
protected function _addBreadcrumb($label, $title=null, $link=null)
{
    if($this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')){
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->addLink($label, $title, $link);
    }
}
```

For me, I didn't care if there were breadcrumbs on the admin page, specifically when importing products or sending emails.  So far, it hasn't caused a problem on the store site itself.  Breadcrumbs are still generating as expected, I can still add to cart, checkout, etc.

**PLEASE NOTE - This is changing a core class in a core class file, which is not the best/borderline bad if not bad.  So I want to emphasize this is/should be a TEMPORARY fix only!!**